# Copy paste entire row if the cell has red/green/Yellow color in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with values based on monthly based and product in 1st column as shown below (Say "sheet1"). This table has conditional formatting applied to highlight cell colors red/yellow/green based on target. So, I want to take only specific month(current month- May) column and want VBA to check, if any cell in that column is Red, select that entire row and copy past it into another sheet for example "Sheet2" with headers.

```
Product   =  Target   Feb Mar Apr May
Wood     >=    5      10  10  10  10
wood     >=    5      28  28  28  28
Tree     >=   12      30  45  60  68
plastic  >=   45      50  50  50  50
tree     >=   50      50  50  50  50
iron     >=   100     64  75  75  80
```

The values will change monthly and even sometimes target, so the coloring can be totally green/yellow/red sometimes. So, I want to automate this process using VBA, to go and check on "Sheet1" every month and pull any rows which has red cell highlighted for that month. OR even a button function could also help, so I can assign this macro to a button, this action should be done by clicking the button. Even it should also clear all rows from earlier month in Sheet2, which might have highlighted in last month but not in this month.

I tried, different ways to do this, its not recognizing the cell color. When I use the random/regular cell out of table and fill with red color and use find(ctrl+f) popup box to highlight using color format, it is working but its not taking the cells which has conditional formatting in a table. So, I don't know if there is a way to identify all the cells in the table which is highlighted in red using VBA.

Comment: This answer should point you in the direction ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50366447/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike I don't think that answer is helpful for this question.

Comment: A couple options here: checking that the original condition logic is met; using a helper column; or checking the `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` of the cell.

Comment: Another option: Use an `AutoFilter` with `Operator:=xlFilterCellColor` (for the column) to move all rows at once

Comment: If you please don't mind attaching a vba for this action, i would appreciate your time.

Comment: Have you done any work toward this yourself yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INPUT (IN WORKSHEET1):

[image: MyImage]

OUTPUT (IN WORKSHEET2):

[image: MyImage]

```
    Sub newnew()
```

> declaring the worksheets, Sheet2 and Sheet3 should be changed to match your sheet names

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim wsTwo As Worksheet
       Set wsTwo = Sheets("Sheet3")
```

> clearing out previous data in wsTwo

```
    wsTwo.Cells.Clear
```

> finding the last row and column for ws with data inside

```
    Dim lastRow As Integer
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastColumn As Integer
        lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

> we are setting up the header here

```
    ws.Range("A1:F1").Copy
    wsTwo.Range("A1:F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

> beginning our loop from the last row and moving upwards till we hit row 2. We are checking if rowNum and lastColumn display format interior color is red. If it is we are taking that range, copying it, then pasting it in wsTwo. Note that we have that rowCounter which we set before entering the for loop. we will use that as a placeholder, incrementing every time that we paste in ws two, so that we don't paste over data we just pasted.

```
     Dim rowCounterWsTwo As Integer
         rowCounterWsTwo = 2

    For rowNum = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(rowNum, lastColumn).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed = vbRed Then
                ws.Range(Cells(rowNum, 1), Cells(rowNum, lastColumn)).Copy
                wsTwo.Range("A2:F2").Insert
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                rowCounterWsTwo = rowCounterWsTwo + 1
            End If
    Next rowNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Please reread the question again, he wants only the column for the current month to be checked for cell color, not all cells in the data range, Hard coding the column will not work because the last column will change every month.  Also, your Insert will flip the rows, so the last row will be on the first row. Paste and last row +1 for sheet2 would probably be the best choice. You might want to edit your answer.

Comment: @GMalc you are absolutely right, fixed based on your input (for some reason I found your descript much clearer than OP). Edited to improve answer. TY

Comment: Thanks for your time and code but, i was able to do the same using a find pop up box and even using your code but as i mentioned in my question that when this color is applied in the background using conditional formatting then its not identifying the red cells/color.               This is only working when, i manually fill the color in each cell. So, i would appreciate if you can please edit the code according to this requirement. Everything is working as i needed except it's not identifying the color if applied through conditional format and even i need headers when copying to sheet2. TY

Comment: Even, i have edited my table where the operators are in separate column. What i am doing here is, i am creating a Name Manager (Comparetotarget) using below formula "evaluate(concatenate(sheet1!D2,Sheet1!$C2,Sheet1!$D2)) which evaluates the values in cells as "10 >= 5", which is applied to all the cells from D2:F7. Then applying the conditional format on top of this cells using "if(not(comparetotarget),if(ABS((D2-$C2/$C2)>5%,"True"))" then cells change to red, if <=5% then yellow and if equal to "comparetotarget" then green. So, when this colors are applied, this vba not identifying the colors

Comment: I switched the check color statement to, Cells(rowNum, lastColumn).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed. make sure that you set the conditional coloring to vb red, same color as in my photo. this should work. let me know.

Comment: Now, its working fine but it's not copying the header to "Sheet2" and even the formatting is changed when copied. So, if you can please add this vba to copy even the "header" and finally after everything copied, apply the same format from "sheet1" to "sheet2". So, the coloring and conditional formats should looks same. I would also appreciate, if you can please add few comments to your code, so i can understand what each line/part is doing, so i can do some adjustments, if required in future. TY @learnAsWeGo

Comment: added a bit more hopefully enough for an upvote and correct answer, take care rockstar

Comment: Hi @learnAsWeGo, Thank you for the detail explanation and yes everything is correct. Except, as we are using rowCounter to avoid pasting over the data just pasted which is working good but it is moving down the headers row below all the cells because the insert option is doing this every time its pasting in A1:F1 cells. I tried to change things but not working around. So, is there any way we can lock the header row once copied and move all the remaining data from cells below it or even we can paste the header in the last. Its also not applying Cond. Format from previous sheet to this sheet. TY

Comment: yea change  wsTwo.Range("A1:F1").Insert to  wsTwo.Range("A2:F2").Insert see edit  also please accept as answer ty

Comment: Thank you so much @learnAsWeGo for your help, i really appreciate your time. Yes, its working now.

Comment: I was also trying to clear cells based on specific range, i declared the range as "dim rn as range" on top and in the clear cells line, i tried to add this but giving me an error " wstwo.rn("A2", selection.end(x1ToRight), selection.End(x1Down)).ClearContents " but its not understand, i think i am doing something wrong here. I was trying to clear based on selecting one cell like "A2" and then ctrl+shift+right to select right most column with data and then down using down instead of right. So, it will select only those specific range to clear contents of it. Can you help, if you don't mind.

Comment: Hi @learnAsWeGo, can i use the copy paste option instead of insert in my code when red cell is identified, because when i am using a copy/paste using source formatting, its pasting on top of one another. So, is there any way i can make them copy same as usual like insert, because as we are going from bottom to top acc to your VBA. so, i want the row to be in same manner while pasting. I would appreciate, if you or anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to set up a counter to keep track of the row number that you are pasting in in sheet2, otherwise you will paste over itself over and over

Comment: as for stretching the range of your copy paste, you have to find a way to replace the F in ws.Range("A1:F1") and wsTwo.Range("A1:F1") with the value in lastColumn...problem is lastColumn is an int. you have to link number with corresponding alphabetical column value...dictionary may be the way to go. goodluck @rockstar

Comment: So, how do i set up a counter to keep track of the row number that i am pasting in sheet2, so it doesn't paste over and over.  I am trying to use this option for pasting which uses source formatting and values. "wsTwo.Range("A2:I2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False" and "wsTwo.Range("A2:I2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False". Which is working fine but just need to paste one after another instead of one over another, instead of using this "wsTwo.Range("A2:I2").Insert"

Comment: Hi @learnAsWeGo, can you help on the counter issue, i just discussed above, i tried different ways but same error pasting one over another. TY